# External Storage MicroSD card

Tags: storage, micro-sd, sd-card

When the phone specs say "Expansion card slot supports microSD™ memory card for up to 128GB additional storage". Is that 128GB for the RAM (short-term memory) or the ROM (long term memory)

Answer (score 6):

That would be for the built-in non-volatile storage<sup>1</sup>, not RAM. 128 GB of RAM is not something you will need in a mobile phone for a long time.

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, ROM is not the correct acronym because it stands for "read-only memory", which the built-in storage of your phone is obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

A microSD card is by it's very nature flash memory (or, in theory, something that pretends to be--but there are no such alternatives these days)--they didn't specify what type because there was no reason to.

As Indrek said, it's long term memory.